# Rollup Q&A: Are tezos rollup all common goods using ctez token? What stops them from having a token?

Tags: tokens, smart-rollup, rollup, ticket

[Question from reddit]

I read that tezos rollups are "common goods that will use ctez or wrapped xtz", is this another feature of them being "enshrined"? What prevents SORUs to use their own token for rollup gas (then exchange it somehow with xtz to pay the L1 blockspace)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from whalesniper

> Tickets enable extreme interoperability across different rollups.
> There will likely be a generic wrapping service that takes any
> FA1.2/FA2 and gives you a standard ticket that can be used on any
> rollup. The job of rollup creators will be to use the same service so
> that users dont have to keep wrapping and unwrapping the same asset.
>
> Rollups can be common goods but they don't have to. For example,
>
> EVM Kernel? Common good. Anyone can bring solidity contracts to this
> rollup and have fun.
>
> Game Kernel? More private. Game logic will likely be specific for a
> specific game. So a custom kernel will be more appropriate.
>
> There's nothing wrong with paying for computation, and gas tokens are
> feasible ways to do that. Gas tokens would be a MUST for the "common
> good" rollups like a big EVM kernel.

Answer from daniel hines

> In short, you can write [your own rollup kernel](https://www.marigold.dev/post/how-to-write-a-rollup-kernel) to do whatever you
> want. You could create your own token for gas on your rollup. However,
> s Ctez is really useful in the context of rollups - it allows Tezos to
> move assets to L2 and reap the benefits of better performance/lower
> fees/etc. while not diluting/sacrificing their governance power.

Answer from nomadic labs

> Nothing prevents a Smart Rollup from using its own token. However,
> using ctez as a universal token for all rollups would make exchanges
> between rollups smoother.